# How do i open Visual Studio 2019 c++ code in Visual Studio 2017 without errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

When i try to open my project created in VS2019 containing the code below in VS2017 i get errors saying that identifiers "setlocale", "strand", "system", "free", "realloc", "malloc", "rand" are undefined. How can i configure my project in VS2019 to be backward compatible with VS2017 compiler?

https://codeshare.io/wndd0K

Comment: You are missing some system includes for those functions: `<cstdlib>`, `<clocale>`, etc. Please look up a reference on which headers are appropriate for each of those includes https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale

Comment: ***How can i configure my project in VS2019 to be backward compatible with VS2017 compiler?*** It's not a configuration setting. The problem is you have missing includes. Just Google the function to lookup the documentation and figure out the proper include  to add.

Comment: You seem to have a broken installation of VS2017, you probably need to repair or reinstall it, rather than try to configure your project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc: [Microsoft C++ porting and upgrading guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-porting-and-upgrading-guide?view=msvc-160)

For projects created in Visual Studio 2010 through 2017, just open the project in Visual Studio 2019.

As far as I'm concerned, you could open Visual Studio 2019 c++ code in Visual Studio 2017 directly.

Accoring to the error,I suggest you could try to add the following code:

`#include <cstdlib>`

`#include <stdlib.h>`

`#include <clocale>`

Comment: @Misha Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.